# get Transfer events from 0x0 address for ERC20 token

Tags: web3js, nodejs, web3js-v0.x

I am trying to get all the events that originate from zero (0x0) address in order to capture the mint activity for my ERC20 token.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var instance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(tokenContractAddress);
var blockNo = web3.eth.blockNumber;
console.log('latest block', blockNo); //able to get blockNo successfully

var result = instance.Transfer({from: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'},
            {fromBlock:4361077, toBlock:'latest'}, 
           (err, res) => {
             console.log(res);
        });
```

However i never get anything in the `res` object and its always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should change this:

```
{from: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'},
        {fromBlock:4361077, toBlock:'latest'}
```

To this:

```
{from: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        fromBlock:4361077, toBlock:'latest'}
```

If it's still not working for you, then you can try this:

```
instance.allEvents().get(function(error, logs) {
    assert(error === null);
    for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        if (logs[i].event == 'Transfer' && logs[i].args.from == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
            console.log(logs[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i assume you mean `logs[i].event == 'Transfer'`

I tried both and the console statement is never executed

Comment: @stud91: Yes, my mistake with that comma there, changed it to `==`. Are you sure that such an event has been fired prior to your attempt?

Comment: yes, please refer to https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x777a2eae2dbabf08d50e822631c54e4304414b45#events